# Importing webpack-exported mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, webpack, mongoose, babeljs, babel-loader

I am working between two packages. In the first one, I define a mongoose (v5.4.19) Schema :

```js
// src/models/index.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose/browser'

const mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  listOfThings: []
})
export default mySchema
```

I build it into a dist file using a standard Webpack config:

```js
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    components: './src/components/index.js',
    models: './src/models/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  mode: "production",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

and the `.babelrc` just loads the env preset and two plugins (object rest spread, react jsx).

In the second package (a Next.js app), I import that schema:

```js
// pages/index.js
import React from 'react'
import mongoose from 'mongoose/browser'
import mySchema from 'myfirstlib/dist/models'

/*
const myDuplicateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  listOfThings: []
})
*/

const myDoc = new mongoose.Document({
  name: 'name',
  listOfThings: []
}, mySchema)

export default () => <div></div>
```

I get the following error as soon as I try to populate the `listOfThings` prop:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$__' of undefined

It occurs somewhere in my webpacked models (`dist/models.js`):

```
  691 | /*!
  692 |  * ignore
> 693 |  */t.exports=function(t,e,n){const r=(n=n||{}).skipDocArrays;let i=0;for(const n of Object.keys(t.$__.activePaths.states.modify)){if(r){const e=t.schema.path(n);if(e&&e.$isMongooseDocumentArray)continue}0===n.indexOf(e+".")&&(delete t.$__.activePaths.states.modify[n],++i)}return i}},function(t,e,n){"use strict";
  694 | /*!
  695 |  * Module dependencies.
  696 |  */const r=n(21).get().Binary,i=n(1),o=n(48).Buffer,s=o.from("").constructor.prototype;function a(t,e,n){let r,s,c,u,l;return r=0===arguments.length||null===arguments[0]||void 0===arguments[0]?0:t,Array.isArray(e)?(c=e[0],u=e[1]):s=e,l="number"==typeof r||r instanceof Number?o.alloc(r):o.from(r,s,n),i.decorate(l,a.mixin),l.isMongooseBuffer=!0,Object.defineProperties(l,{validators:{value:[],enumerable:!1},_path:{value:c,enumerable:!1},_parent:{value:u,enumerable:!1}}),u&&"string"==typeof c&&Object.defineProperty(l,"_schema",{value:u.schema.path(c)}),l._subtype=0,l}
```

- It works fine if I don't try to assign a value to my `listOfThings`.
- It also works fine if I init `myDoc` with `myDuplicateSchema` instead of `mySchema` (even if `listOfThings` is a non-empty array).
- I can also init `myDoc` with `new mongoose.Schema(courseSchema.obj)`

When I `console.log(mySchema, myDuplicateSchema)` they appear as JS objects with the same content but with different "types" (I'm not sure I'm using the right word here): the first one is printed as a `$` whereas the second one is printed as a `Schema`.

So if I understand correctly, when the Schema is webpacked in my first package, it loses something that makes it impossible to use in my second package. I tried adding the webpack config options listed [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html) but the result is the same.

Is there something I can do to make my Schema available in my second package?